# Link exe with application? c#

Tags: c#, exe

How to auto close an exe if my application close or forced to close. Is it possible to link exe file with my application? I can start exe inside win form but i want to start it outside the winform.

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to use the `Process` class and get an instance using either `GetProcessByName` or `GetProcessById`. Then you can call `Kill` on the resulting object:

```
Process.GetProcessByName("process-name.exe").Kill();
```

This is a fairly nuclear option, though, so alternatively, you can instead try `CloseMainWindow` to attempt a more elegant close:

```
Process.GetProcessByName("process-name.exe").CloseMainWindow();
```

Comment: Is it close the exe if my app crashes?

Comment: @Çağıl Uyar In the app that must be closed monitor the app that crashes.

Comment: Something familiar, but kill the process with a processID: `Process.GetProcessById(ID).Kill();`